# Android TCP socket not working

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a server running on my desktop with an Android app.
I tried making a desktop Java program to test the connection and it worked with this code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

It instantly prints the server welcome message, and I can see a new connection on the server.

However, the same code running on Android (on a separate thread) can't make the connection and I end up with a socket timeout exception.

```
private class NetworkThread implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            BufferedReader in
                    = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            textStatus.setText(in.readLine());
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Log.i("Network", ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The thread is created here

```
public void onConnectBtnClick(View view) {
        new Thread(new NetworkThread()).start();
    }
```

HOST is the IP of the server and PORT is the port and have the same values in the Java and Android clients.
I have opened the port in my firewall but the android app still can't make the connection, and I get

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to GPC/192.168.1.5 (port 399): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

The manifest has the INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a network connectivity problem, not a Java or coding problem. See if you can Telnet to that host:port. NB You never close the socket, so you're leaking connections; you only read one line from the connection; and you don't check that line for null.

Comment: @EJP I can Telnet to the host and communicate with the server just fine from my own computer but not from another one connected to the same network. I have the port opened on the firewall, do I need to do anything else?